# Ionic android build crashes at :processDebugResources

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm still new in Ionic, so I programmed an App a few weeks ago, something went wrong and crash while using command "ionic build android".
"ionic serve" also doesn't work.

Here is the output of the build:

```
Running command: /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/hooks/after_prepareicons_and_splashscreens.js /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business
Running command: /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business
Running command: /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/cordova/build 
ANDROID_HOME=/home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
Running: /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/gradlew        cdvBuildDebug -b /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/   build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132311Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm830Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources
/home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/archiver/node_modules/file-utils/node_modules/isbinaryfile/tests/fixtures/03_Руководство_по_эксплуатации.rst: error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.
:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar -M /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.titaniumtemplates.local_business -0 apk --output-text-symbols /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/archiver/node_modules/file-utils/node_modules/isbinaryfile/tests/fixtures/03_Руководство_по_эксплуатации.rst: error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.208 secs

/home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/USERNAME/IONIC_Workspace/local-business/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I haven't used the file *03_Руководство_по_эксплуатации.rst* in my project and don't know what to do with it.

Can someone give hints how to solve my problem.

Comment: Did you use some special characters inside your app name or app identifier? In that case try just normal letter 'A' - 'Z'.

Answer (score 0):

The :processDebugResources task tries to copy the 03_Руководство_по_эксплуатации.rst to the resource folders in your platform projects.

There might be different reasons why cordova does want to copy this file:

- it is needed by an libary
- it is configured in your `config.xml`
- permissions error
- some caching problem

You cold try:

- delete your platforms folder, this will cause `ionic build android` to regenerate the hole folder (ist like deleting the cache)
- check if the file exists and create an empty dummyfile
- check if the file is mentioned in your `config.xml` and remove that line
- reinstall all dependencies
- uninstall all unnecessary plugins
- remove all platforms and add them agian